# [Dead]How to successfully POST to an old ASP.NET site utilizing Asynchronous Postback

Tags: php, javascript, asp.net, curl, updatepanel

[Update] Unfortunately I never had an opportunity to solve this problem. However, there are some interesting responses below that are worth a try for other readers looking to do something similar.

I'm trying to parse data from a site running ASP.NET. This site has a login page that I've successfully traversed (using a legitimate account) and stored the cookie for, but when I get deeper into the site I need to navigate it by updating UpdatePanels via Asynchronous Postbacks. The UpdatePanels contain the data that I want.

I'm trying to do this all using PHP and curl. I can successfully load the initial page. When I POST to my target page with all the relevant data (obtained via Firefox's Tamper Data plugin), the echoed result returned from curl always clears my page. Typically, echoing the result would just print out (or spew some error/garbled text) further down the page. curl_error() doesn't print out anything, so it's something wrong with what's being returned to me.

I'm at wits end about how to go about this from here. Please tell me if: a) you know what error I'm getting, b) if this is even going to be possible with exclusively PHP, and c) if, conversely, I need to brush off javascript to interact with ASP.NET's UpdatePanels.

```
$uri = "TARGETURL";
$cl=curl_init();
curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_URL, $uri);
curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0');
curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/tmp/cookie2.txt");
curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$postdata=array(

    "__VIEWSTATE" => $viewstate,
    "OTHER DATA" => "asdfkljsddflkjshdjf",
    "__ASYNCPOST" => "true",
);
echo "<PRE>";
print_r($postdata);
echo "</PRE>";
curl_setopt ($cl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
$result = curl_exec($cl); // execute the curl command
echo $result;
```

Here is the Header and Body I am receiving back from the server (e-mailed to myself to bypass the page-clearing happening with the echo statement):

```
HEADER RESPONSE: 
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Cache-Control: no-cache 
Pragma: no-cache 
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1 
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5 
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Set-Cookie: culture=en-US; expires=Tue, 27-Nov-2012 20:02:37 GMT; path=/ 
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Date: Mon, 28 Nov 2011 20:02:37 GMT
Content-Length: 112 
BODY RESPONSE: 
69|dataItem||<script type="text/javascript">window.location="about:blank"</script>|11|pageRedirect||/Error.aspx|
```

This explains the problem I'm getting with the page going blank (javascript redirecting my browser output). It also seems to indicate that the header isn't the issue as I'd be getting an HTTP error from bad header values.

Comment: Just have to temper data of the ajax request and mimic it completely. Whats the target url? Probably missing like `__EVENTTARGET` `__EVENTARGUMENT`

Comment: It was removed for confidentiality. Same with __EVENTTARGET and __EVENTARGUMENT (though I know those two have the right parameters).

Comment: But yeah since it's not SSL you can easily Sniff the traffic using Wireshark and see which line in the request or headers you are not sending.. try to mimic everything to the byte.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I checked out Wireshark and decided I'd likely need to invest a large amount of time into it. I'm going to come back to that when I get an opportunity. Thanks.

Comment: have a look at [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) - much easier to use than Wireshark and also includes plugins to auto-magically convert captured requests into code

Comment: probably kicking in an open door, but isn't it easier to just ask the site you are scraping to ask if they have an API, RSS feed or maybe even generated XML file to access the data you want.

Comment: @David: Have you found a solution for your problem? Will you mark any of the answers as accepted (this is a help-reward site)?

Comment: Actually, the company I was working for ended up abandoning this awhile back. The problem was never solved and unfortunately I don't have a login to test it again to see if any more of the recent responses would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A. You state in your request that you are Firefox browser:

`curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0');`

Do not claim you're Firefox:

- if you cannot process scripts (as Firefox can and does)
- if you want to prevent ASP.NET from sending you a partial rendering response

Make your own user agent name, or don't send it at all.

ASP.NET checks if user agent supports callbacks:
[HttpCapabilitiesBase.SupportsCallback Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpcapabilitiesbase.supportscallback.aspx)

B. Don't send `__ASYNCPOST = true` (give it a try).

Answer (score 1):

Here you are an addapted approach that works for me:

```
    public function doPostbackToAspDotNetPage()
{
    $uri = '*** THE_URL ***';
    $cl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_URL, $uri);
    curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0');
    curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, '*** OPTIONAL ***');
    curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
    curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    // Just in case the url is https and the certification gives some kind of error
    curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    $postdata = array(
        '__EVENTTARGET' => '*** A value such as: SOME_ID$ctl20$ctl02 ***',
        '__EVENTARGUMENT' => ' *** OPTIONAL ***',
        "__VIEWSTATE" => '*** REQUIRED BUNCH OF CHARACTERS ***',
        "__ASYNCPOST" => "true",
        '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR' => '*** OPTIONAL ***',
        '__EVENTVALIDATION' => "*** REQUIRED BUNCH OF CHARACTERS ***",

    );
    curl_setopt($cl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);

    $result = curl_exec($cl);
    if (!$result) {
        echo sprintf('ERROR:%s', PHP_EOL);
        echo curl_error($cl);
    } else {
        echo $result;
    }
    curl_close($cl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A different approach can be use a very useful PHP tool (a class emulating browser behavior) that do *all* the job to keep trace of all fields, do the post/get by *clicking* on links or buttons.

Here the link:

[simpletest](http://simpletest.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue about php and curl, but if I understand Correctly, you are trying to send info to an ASP page. Maybe the problem is that the page has the `CausesValidation` option activated. so, the server is not allowing external POSTs to the page.