# Using curl on server - how to redirect javascript requests to target server?

Tags: php, javascript, asp.net, html, postback

So I'm running a crawler on my server and I'm needing to execute javascript to gain access to some of the data on my target site (target being the one I want to crawl). I had a question regarding a different approach to the problem here, but it's not needed for answering this one: [[Dead]How to successfully POST to an old ASP.NET site utilizing Asynchronous Postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283459/how-to-successfully-post-to-an-old-asp-net-site-utilizing-asynchronous-postback)

My javascript is executed in the browser I call my php crawler from. The problem is that all javascript requests are targeted back at my own server rather than the target site (I get lead to links like /index.php on my own site rather than the target site).

My experience with javascript is pretty minimal and I'm not sure how I should redirect my requests to my target. Here is an example of a javascript function from the page that I'm calling:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['aspnetForm'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.aspnetForm;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>
```

... and the way that I call it:

```
echo "<SCRIPT language='javascript'>__doPostBack('-254870369', '')</SCRIPT>";
```

Is there some way of aliasing the server address from my own server to the target server or doing some other kind of handy workaround that would fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to inject javascript in the target.
You can use [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to study all request made by the target. Wireshark is a quite hard to master but powerful. Instead you can try the `net` tab of the [firebug addon](http://getfirebug.com/).

Once you know how the target send requests and receive data from their server, you can use curl to imitate the request/receiving data. You don't need any more to build crawlers.

If this not answers your question explain a little more the scenario.

Comment: I'll have to look into that further. I tried Wireshark and it seemed incredibly complex/tedious (hundreds of requests to look through and I didn't know what I was looking for). I'm sure it would be a useful tool if I spent some time learning how to use it - but right now I'm at a make-it/break-it point and need something ASAP. I might need to  come up with a hacky fix and invest some time into Wireshark later.