# Passing stored cookies from PHP crawler to Javascript in browser and using them from browser

Tags: php, javascript, cookies

How would I accomplish this? I'm using curl with PHP on the server, then executing the postback function in my browser through Javascript. The server handles the login and navigation, but after much trial and error it seems I need to access the client side functions to get the data I need.

Essentially me situations looks like this:

```
T = Target
S = Server
B = Browser

S <- B - Browser calls php script on server
T <- S - Server logs into Target, gets cookies
S <- B - Browser gets returned HTML/JS from server
T <- B - Browser executes JS code
T <X-B - Browser fails to navigate because it doesn't have the stored cookies
```

How would I use the cookies from the Javascript end? I apologize if this seems like too simple  a question, but I'm having a very difficult time finding good information on the topic and my knowledge of Javascript is minimal.

For a reference to other related questions, see here: 
[Using curl on server - how to redirect javascript requests to target server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303474/using-curl-on-server-how-to-redirect-javascript-requests-to-target-server)

For the most part however, this and the one prior to that have been worked around in other ways and this is my current roadblock.

Comment: Are you using curl on the server (ie PHP's curl functions), and want to pass the client side cookies to the final server destination?

Comment: Exactly. I need to get the cookies from my server, to my browser (where Javascript is executing) so I can run them when my browser gets re-directed from the Javascript calls I'm making.

Comment: Run what? Cookies are stored in the browser, and associated with the domain that set them. Whenever the browser sends a request to the domain that set those cookies it will send the cookies along as well. Not sure I understand the question.

Comment: The target site, T is accessed and logged in to via my server, S. Then, my browser, B calls javascript functions to interact with the site, but my browser doesn't have the cookies stored.

T <- S server logs in   |
S has cookies   |
S <- B gets echoed html/JS from server   |
T <- B browser calls JS functions, but doesn't have cookies stored   |

Comment: If you are saying browser makes request to domain1.com (sending any cookies that belong to domain1.com) and domain1.com sends a curl request to domain2.com, and you want to pass along the same cookies then please restate the question.

Comment: Or do you want the cookies sent by domain2.com to be passed on by domain1.com to the client?

Comment: I clarified my situation in the original post with a diagram.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` when calling [curl_exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php), which will return the entire response from the server. You'll then need to parse this to extract the Set-Cookie headers (there may be more than one), and then set those same cookies on the current response.